# How do I code an image generator that will generate every 64 x 64 picture ever?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css

So I want to make a website where I can generate EVERY SINGLE Minecraft skin (which are 64 px by 64 px) possible (And put it up on a web page), by using many different combinations of many different coloured pixels in many different positions. (Or in fact, ALL of them.)

Similar to a generator which generates every black/white pixel combination in a 1x2 grid (I made a gif on that here, https://gyazo.com/071a5d482852fc8eea9963e841f5dbc1, but it's very small so you'll have to look at your screen closely), except using all colours and on a much larger scale.

But the problem is, I don't know what coding language to code it in.

And there are many different coding languages, like PHP, SQL, JavaScript, Ruby, Python, and others, but I just don't know which one to use to create a generator like this. (And I also don't know how to actually get it onto the web page so it can generate onto the web page real-time.)

If anyone could help me on this then that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't done some quick math, have you?

There are 64*64 = 4096 pixels to choose a color for. If you choose from only 256 colors for each pixel, then you'd have 256^4096 possible pictures, which is about 1.4*10^9864. That's a number with 9865 decimal digits.

Now let's put any memory issues aside, suppose you need just a nanosecond to generate one picture. Then you'll be waiting

(256^4096)/(31557600*10^9)

or roughly 4.5*10^9847 years for your result.

I don't think the universe lives that long pal :/

Comment: An important point, though it does make the assumption that the patterns are to be generated ahead of time (or at least without waiting), as opposed to on demand.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I assumed that OP wants them all up on his site ("And put it up on a web page"). He'll never have enough memory or time.

Comment: Love this kind of arguments